# Can Flex SDK be linked agaisnt from a vanilla objective-c xcode app to use its RTMP streaming capabilties

Tags: objective-c, apache-flex, air

I have been working with FMS and am thinking of developing and iOS application. We're already setup to stream HLS so its not a huge problem, but I know that flex/air ios apps can play video over RTMP, and I was curious if I could export a static library from a flex/air project and link it to a native iOS / objective-c cocoa app to just leverage the RTMP / Video stuff.

Was curious if anyone knew anything about this or had done it successfully?

Comment: You can call Objective C Code from inside a Flex app using a Native Extension.  But, you cannot call ActionScript code from within an Objective C application.

Comment: @Reboog711 is right. Your user interface would have to be coded in Adobe Air. You can call your Objective-C code using an Air Native Extension (ANE). Your Objective-C code can dispatch events to the Air application through the ANE.

Comment: So i cant export a static library and link to it? I thought that at the end of the air compile the as code was native code